# Searching for a specifc given hex string in multiple images on Linux

Tags: linux, string, grep, pattern-matching, xxd

I am doing some research on image processing and I wanted to know if its possible to search for a specific hex string/byte array in various images. It would be great if it gives me a list of images that has that specific string. Basically what grep -r "" does. For some reason grep doesn't do the job. I am not familiar with strings. I did had a look at "man strings" but it didn't help much. Anyways, I would like to look for a specific hex string say "0002131230443" (or even specific byte array i.e. base64 string) in several images in the same folder. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I found this code which exactly does what I want using xxd and grep. Please find the command below:
    xxd -p /your/file | tr -d '\n' | grep -c     '22081b00081f091d2733170d123f3114'

FYI:
It'll return 1 if the content matches, 0 else.

xxd -p converts the file to plain hex dump, tr -d '\n' removes the newlines added by xxd, and grep -c counts the number of lines matched.

Does anyone know how to run the code above in a specific directory using bash script. I have around 400 images and I want it to return only 400 (i.e. a string matching count) if all the 400 images have that particular string. I found this script code below but it runs the same code over and over for 400 times returning either 0 or 1 each time:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=/FILEPATH/*
for f in $FILES
do
   echo "PROCESSING $f FILES"
   echo "-------------------"
   XXD -u $f | grep ABCD
   echo "-------------------"
done
```

Thanks guys.

Plasma33

Comment: Yes you are right. I meant bash script. I corrected it now. Sorry unfortunately I am a frequent windows user.

Comment: Yes, that IS unfortunate ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=/FILEPATH/*
for f in $files
do
  grep -m 1 -P '\x22\x08\x1b\x00' < "$f"
done | wc -l
```

Comment: Perfect!! It worked exactly like I wanted. Great effort. Thanks heaps!! I didn't had to interchange the byte order. For instance: To grep for 22081b00 I simple did consecutively '\x22\x08\x1b\x00'. It didn't work when I interchanged the byte string as you demonstrated. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, the problem on my side was different output of `hexdump file` and `hexdump -C file`. I've updated my answer.